# Pergola roof drainage

Tags: roof, drain

We have a Pergola with no roof but only slats. So pergola was built with no slope. We are fixing to install a roof and am thinking of sloping pergola toward the house due to gutter system home has. Is this asking for house
leak problem in the future? Pergola is 30'w x 20'L.

Comment: "Gutter system" as in roof gutters? Are you proposing a vee shape in the roof with a gutter at the bottom of the vee? Do you get regular winter snows?

Comment: You are almost doubling the amount of water draining into the gutter.  Most standard size gutters might have problems keeping up/draining all the water away, overflowing the sides.  Might be time for plan B.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend draining the pergola to the house gutter, unless you perhaps have 6" gutters and a house roof on the smaller side.  I would rather have a separate gutter for the pergola (which will now be a patio cover, not a pergola), or drain to a separate gutter away from the house.  You should really provide pics or sketches here.